# Is it possible to start a program from the command line with input from a file without terminating the program?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program that users can run using the command line. Once running, it receives and processes commands from the keyboard. It's possible to start the program with input from disk like so: `$ ./program < startScript.sh`. However, the program quits as soon as the script finishes running. Is there a way to start the program with input from disk using `<` that does not quit the program and allows additional keyboard input to be read?

Answer (score 1):

```
(cat foo.txt; cat) | ./program
```

I.e., create a subshell (that's what the parentheses do) which first outputs the contents of foo.txt and after that just copies whatever the user types. Then, take the combined output of this subshell and pipe it into stdin of your program.

Note that this also works for other combinations. Say you want to start a program that always asks the same questions. The best approach would be to use "expect" and make sure the questions didn't change, but for a quick workaround, you can also do something like this:

```
(echo y; echo $file; echo n) | whatever
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does? I'm a novice shell script programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But doesn't this have the same effect as appending to the original script? In any case, I tried what you suggested and, while it allows additional input, it doesn't return the prompt of the program.

Comment: Your question didn't ask about the prompt. That's a considerably more difficult thing to do from the outside. Expect might be able to do it, I don't know.

Comment: No need for two invocations of `cat`.  `{ cat file -; } | ...` works as well.

Comment: True. And then we can get rid of the subshell, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use system("pause")(in bash it's just "pause") in your program so that it does not exit immediatly.

There are alternatives such as

- dummy read
- infinite loop
- sigsuspend
- many more

Comment: I should clarify that I can only modify the script that's run from disk and not the program itself.

Comment: I do not remember the way for bash to wait until a program finishes.

Comment: I fear you may need to resort to remembering the pid of the executable, and constantly poll kill -0 on it.

Comment: try doing http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/76531-waiting-background-process-finish.html it may work.

Comment: Bash waits for a program to finish unless you explicitly say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the `program` is coded. This cannot be achieved from writing code in `startScript.sh`, if that is what you're trying to achieve.

What you could do is write a `callingScript.sh` that asks for the input first and then calls the `program < startScript.sh`.

Comment: startScript.sh is not executed in the call above, it is given as the input.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the script to the program and get the prompt back for the program?

Comment: Can you please explain with an example what flow are you expecting? I'd be glad to help but I don't think I understand what exactly you want here :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this

```
BODY=`./startScript.sh`
if [ -n "$BODY" ]
    then cat "$BODY" |./program
fi
```